# How to make a picture change randomly in a website?

Tags: javascript, html, image, random

I want to make a website that the user will decide something. The user will click what he or she chose.

I want to know how to make the picture change to a random other picture everytime the user clicks it.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've posted an answer up for you to explain the general concept. However, if you've already started on your website and want a particular answer designed directly around the code you're using, post it up for us and we can "tailor" you a more direct response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an array with all the urls of the images you wanna use.
e.g.

HTML:

```
<img id='the-image-to-change'/>
```

JS:

```
var imageUrls = [
 'http://placehold.it/255x255&text=A',
 'http://placehold.it/255x255&text=B',
// ... more
  'http://placehold.it/255x255&text=Z'
];
```

if you're not using jQuery:

```
var img = document.getElementById('the-image-to-change');
img.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.src = imageUrls[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageUrls.length)];
});
```

if jQuery (has not been tested)

```
img = $('#the-image-to-change');
img.on('click', function() {
    this.src = imageUrls[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageUrls.length)];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the type of effect you want. Basically you're storing your images in an array, then you're going to randomly pick an index, then display it.

```
var yourImages = ["image1.png","image2.png","image3.png"];

var randomImage = Math.round(Math.random()*yourImages.length);
function displayImage()
{
document.write(yourImages[randomImage]);
}
```

---

Here is an example that's more geared toward what you asked, after I read your question again. If the user clicks on the image, it'll change to a random one.

JS:

```
<img id="currentImage" src="defaultImage.png" onclick="changePicture()">

<script>
  function changePicture(){
   var yourImages = ["image1.png","image2.png","image3.png"];
   var randomImage = Math.round(Math.random()*yourImages.length);
   var setImg = document.getElementById("currentImage").src;
   setImg = yourImages[randomImage];
  }
</script>
```

jQuery:

```
<img id="currentImage" src="defaultImage.png">

<script>
 $("#currentImage").click(function(){
    var yourImages = ["image1.png","image2.png","image3.png"];
    var randomImage = Math.round(Math.random()*yourImages.length);
    $("#currentImage").attr("src", yourImages[randomImage]);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of your picture, and use

```
Math.random();
```

To select a random index from your picture array that will be shown??

Comment: Can you make an example?